# How to show full product page on home (but show different custom block than product page)

Tags: magento2, widget, custom-block, home-page

I have a one product store in Magento 2, and want to make it easy to order as soon as possible. 
So i want to have on the homepage everything that there is on the product page, like order button, quantity, reviews etc, an exact copy of the product page.

(The product widget is not enough, because that way you cant order directly from the homepage with quantity etc and there is missing a lot of information)

The best thing to do is, make the product page the homepage by setting the product url as home. 
But... i want to have a custom block on the homepage above the product with a slider. 
That is ofcourse possible, but then i don't want that slider on the "original" product page. 
This way i also have besides the homepage, the normal product page where customers can order the product.

I hope that my question makes sense. 
As you hopefully understand i am looking to include the full product page into my homepage, or find a way to show a custom block only on the homepage (but that will be the product page) and not on the product page itself.

Thanks for helping out!

**Edit:**

Maybe this is a better way for asking.
If I can set a block to show only on homepage, i can achieve what i want. 
So i have set Default Web URL to catalog/product/view/id/1 to show the full product page on home. 
Now i want to show a block on the homepage, but not on the productpage if i would visit that page itself. 
I tried to edit cms_index_index.xml but (ofcourse) it only works on cms pages and not when you set product page as home.